# ArcGIS Server 10 Rest Admin login

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I am trying to login to the http://myserver/arcgis/rest/admin page and when I log in with credentials I get no error message but I am returned to the same login page.  If I put in bad credentials I get an error message saying bad login.  I can login to the rest/services page and the ArcGIS Server Manager Site.

I found this but I am not sure if this applies http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=204&f=2388&t=257171

It looks like I am using a reverse proxy..from looking in the rest.config file under the rest directory.  Does anyone have a clue on what I should investigate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are returned to the same login page, do you get an address like:
http://myserver/ArcGIS/rest/admin/login?redirect=http%3a%2f%2fmyserver%2farcgis%2frest%2fadmin%2fcache

I am not sure the reason, but sometimes when I try to directly access a REST admin page, it goes to this redirect loop.
If you end up here, try accessing the page you want directly, e.g.
http://myserver/ArcGIS/rest/admin/cache
http://myserver/ArcGIS/rest/admin/sd
http://myserver/ArcGIS/rest/admin/generateToken
You will be asked to login again, but when you do it should then redirect you to the correct page.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your event-view logs; you will often see .Net level errors inserted there that may help you see the issue.
 For sure make sure you are logging in with a account that is a member of the agsadmin group on the server.

Comment: I am logging on with an account that is part of the agsadmin group. I have created a GIS server admin connection from ArcCatalog and I can log into AGS Manager.  Thanks..I will check the .Net level errors.

Comment: Also, I've found that your login name is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, it does get matched.

Answer (score 2):

I marked blord-castillo as correct but I did not test but it was redirecting me.  I had ArcGIS Server 10 SP1 and SP2 installed ( I was told this was addressed in one of them) and it worked.  Install the service packs blord-castillo if you can and report back...thanks guys.

Comment: We have SP1 installed right now, so I guess that must mean SP2 fixes it. I found the problem to be fairly random; I can only occasionally generate it by trying to access pages inside the admin console directly. Since I rarely do that, I rarely run into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue today - changing to use the correct port (and SSL) solved it, e.g. `https://myserver:8399/ArcGIS/rest/admin/`